# How to add two strings

Tags: c

I have a file, `cr.c`.

```
void main(int argCount, char **args) {
    system("/usr/bin/javac " + args[1]);
}
```

When I try to compile, it gives me an error:

`cr.c: In function ‘main’:
cr.c:6:30: error: invalid operands to binary + (have ‘char *’ and ‘char *’)
     system("/usr/bin/javac " + args[1]);
                              ^`

I have tried to fix it by replacing `+` with `.`, as I that is one way of joining strings in PHP. It was just a guess.

I do not know why this is happening. Please explain why this is happening, and **how to fix it**. I would not like for somebody else to judt show me what to type instead, as I want to learn.

Thanks!

Comment: the `+` operator doesn't work on strings like you would assume or expect.

Comment: I know that. "It was just a guess"

Comment: Research string handling functions such as `strcat` although you cannot concatenate the argument to the literal `"/usr/bin/javac "`. But you can initialise an array with adequate size to hold both strings (and terminator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably used to high level languages where you can concatenate strings with the `+` sign.

In C, you can use `strcat`:

```
char buffer[100] = "Hello";
strcat(buffer, " World");
```

Comment: What library do I need to to import/include?

Comment: #include <string.h>

Comment: Wouldn't strncat be much safer, especially when the string is user input.

Comment: @hetepeperfan: What is the length you pass to `strcnat()`?  Suppose you are concatenating onto a variable `char target[64];` — is it correct to write `strncat(target, user_provided_string, sizeof(target));`?  If you don't know, you should go look it up.  The answer is actually "No — that's wrong, even if `target[0] == '\0';`"!  And that's why `strncat()` is not safer; it has a weird interface and is far too easy to get wrong.  Don't use `strncat()`!

Comment: @jonathanleffler Thanks for the warning! I see that `strncat` uses the size argument for the source and not for the destination. So `strncat` still happily writes beyond the allocated size of destination, thats a proper beginners pitfall!

Answer (score 1):

The `+` operator does not concat strings. You can call `strcat` to concat the two strings together.

Comment: But you first better ensure that the target string is large enough to hold the new string

Answer (score 0):

to concatenate two strings:

```
char *buffer = malloc( strlen( stringOne ) + strlen( stringTwo ) + 1 );
if( !buffer )
{ // then malloc failed
    perror( "malloc failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, malloc successful

strcpy( buffer, stringOne );
strcat( buffer, stringTwo );
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for your question.
C is a structured language and here you cant use "."(Member operator) or +(Add operator) as like as c# java Cpp php or javascript.
You can simply use the string header file and the predefined functions to make it possible.